# What does "Open Vamp" mean?

Tags: terminology, jazz, trombone, latin-jazz

Playing the trumbone in BRAZIL from S.K.Russel and Ary Barroso a few weeks ago i fell over the sign "Open Vamp" in the trombone 2 part (in bar 10).

Please help: what does this mean and how to play it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A **[vamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostinato#Vamp)** is a repeating musical figure, like a guitar riff. In jazz, Latin jazz, and musical theater it’s often given for the accompaniment so that they can repeat as necessary during intros or solos, in which case it may be noted as “vamp until ready” or “vamp until cue.” Depending on the style and band, players may improvise on the vamp. The “open vamp” appears synonymous with “vamp till ready.”

Comment: Great. That's it. There are indeed two bars silence before that can be repeated until cue...

Answer (score 7):

A vamp is a pattern, usually a simple pattern like one or two chords, that you keep repeating for the purpose of getting into a groove or letting one of the musicians take a solo.